# Как сравнить два списка по элементно с помощью Comparator?

Tags: java

Есть два списка на входе . Первый состоит из одного элемента - `(1)` , а второй список из трех `(1,2,3)` . Есть метод , который их сравнивает:

```
@Override
public int compare(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {

}
```

Вопрос: как реализовать сравнение, если у них разные длины? Чтобы в результате метод возвращал `-1`.

Comment: Если просто сравнить размерность, то можно добавить `return (null != left && null != right ? (left.size() != right.size() ? -1 : left.size()) : -1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
    if ( o1 == o2 ) return 0;
    if ( o1 == null || o2 == null ) return o1 == null ? -1 : 1;
    if ( o1.size() != o2.size() ) return o1.size() < o2.size() ? -1 : 1;
    int comp;
    for (int i = 0; i < o1.size(); i++) {
        if ( (comp = o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i))) != 0 ) {
            // return comp < 0 ? -1 : 1;
            return comp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```